# change filtration criteriain smartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, filtering, smartgwt

i am developing a smartGWT app, and i want to filter the listGrid fields , in a way other than the default one , (ie. the default filtration is based on dearching on a contains matching )

to be more spastic ill give an example :

if a filed have 2 values  one of them is the word "valid" and the other is the word "invalid" then the filtration works correctly for searching the word invalid but when i want to see "valid" , it will give me all the "valid" and "invalid" words since "invalid" consists of "in"+"valid"

```
registeredDate = new DataSourceDateField("registrationDate", voc.registeredDate());  
registeredDate.setRequired(true);

verificationDate = new DataSourceDateField("lastVerificationDate", voc.verificationDate());  
verificationDate.setRequired(true);
```

the same as every other field

this is how i fill records :

```
registeredUsersRecords = new ListGridRecord[registeredUsers.length()];

ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
                record.setAttribute(ID, user.getId());
                record.setAttribute("firstName", user.getFirstName());
                record.setAttribute("lastName", user.getLastName());
                record.setAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
                record.setAttribute("userMainType", type);
                record.setAttribute("isActivated", (user.isActivated())? voc.active(): voc.inActive());
                record.setAttribute("country", user.getSelectedCountry().getValue());
                record.setAttribute("companyName", user.getCompanyName());
                record.setAttribute("registrationDate", user.getRegistrationDate());
                record.setAttribute("lastVerificationDate", user.getVerificationDate());
                registeredUsersRecords[i] = record;
```

and then i put them into datasource :

```
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setClientOnly(true);
    ds.setFields(fName, lName, email, type,typeDetails, status, country, companyName, registeredDate,verificationDate);
    for(int i = 0; i< registeredUsersRecords.length; i++){
        ds.addData(registeredUsersRecords[i]);
    }
    registeredUsersListGrid.setDataSource(ds);
    registeredUsersListGrid.fetchData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think [FilterEditorSubmitHandler](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/events/FilterEditorSubmitHandler.html) will solve your problem.**

---

I have already posted a sample code at your last question here [date filtering not working in smart gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111935/date-filtering-not-working-in-smart-gwt?answertab=votes#tab-top).

You have to do some modification in it as shown below:

**Note:** In the below sample code I have replaced the filter criteria operator from `ICONTAINS` to `STARTS_WITH`. Modify it as per your requirement.

--EDIT--

Complete code:

```
    class User {
        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private Date registrationDate;

        public User(int id, String firstName, Date registrationDate) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public Date getRegistrationDate() {
            return registrationDate;
        }

    }

    DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    User[] registeredUsers = new User[] { new User(1, "valid", format.parse("01/20/2014")),
            new User(2, "invalid", format.parse("05/20/2013")),
            new User(3, "valid", format.parse("02/20/2014")) };

    ListGridRecord[] registeredUsersRecords = new ListGridRecord[registeredUsers.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < registeredUsers.length; i++) {
        User user = registeredUsers[i];
        ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
        record.setAttribute("id", user.getId());
        record.setAttribute("firstName", user.getFirstName());
        record.setAttribute("registrationDate", user.getRegistrationDate());
        registeredUsersRecords[i] = record;
    }

    DataSourceDateField registeredDate = new DataSourceDateField("registrationDate", "Date");
    DataSourceTextField firstName = new DataSourceTextField("firstName", "Name");
    DataSourceIntegerField id = new DataSourceIntegerField("id", "ID");
    id.setRequired(true);
    id.setPrimaryKey(true);
    id.setHidden(true);

    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setClientOnly(true);
    ds.setFields(id, firstName, registeredDate);
    for (int i = 0; i < registeredUsersRecords.length; i++) {
        ds.addData(registeredUsersRecords[i]);
    }

    final ListGrid registeredUsersListGrid = new ListGrid();

    registeredUsersListGrid.setDataSource(ds);
    registeredUsersListGrid.fetchData();
    registeredUsersListGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true);

    registeredUsersListGrid.addFilterEditorSubmitHandler(new FilterEditorSubmitHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onFilterEditorSubmit(FilterEditorSubmitEvent event) {

            event.cancel();

            if (event.getCriteria() != null) {

                AdvancedCriteria advancedCriteria = event.getCriteria().asAdvancedCriteria();

                // store only single criteria for each field(column)
                Map<String, Criterion> criterions = new HashMap<String, Criterion>();
                for (final Criterion criterion : advancedCriteria.getCriteria()) {

                    System.out.println(criterion.getFieldName());
                    System.out.println(criterion.getValueAsString());
                    System.out.println(criterion.getOperator());

                    if (criterion.getOperator() == OperatorId.ICONTAINS) {
                        Criterion newCritearia = new Criterion(criterion.getFieldName(),
                                OperatorId.STARTS_WITH, criterion.getValueAsString());
                        criterions.put(criterion.getFieldName(), newCritearia);
                    } else {
                        criterions.put(criterion.getFieldName(), criterion);
                    }

                }

                if (criterions.size() > 0) {
                    AdvancedCriteria filterCriteria = new AdvancedCriteria(OperatorId.AND,
                            criterions.values().toArray(new Criterion[] {}));
                    registeredUsersListGrid.fetchData(filterCriteria);
                }

            }

        }
    });

    Button button = new Button("Clear all filters");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            registeredUsersListGrid.fetchData();
        }
    });

    VLayout layout = new VLayout();
    layout.setWidth("200px");
    layout.setHeight("200px");

    layout.addMember(button);
    layout.addMember(registeredUsersListGrid);
    layout.draw();
```

Comment: no it has bugs , and i dont know how to deal with it

Comment: Please can you tell me what bug are you talking about so that I can solve it.

Comment: thanx for your Interest , when i fill the filter and press inter , then no data appears in the list grid, ill list the debugging in a minute

Comment: What's printing on console? I have added some SOPs in code to check the applied criteria.

Comment: suppose i want to filter the values of isActivated Field  fo get words starts with "in" then what appear on console is 

isActivated
in
ICONTAINS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51180/discussion-between-mohammad-and-braj)